# Cross-application tracing in Node.js

Tags: node.js

Is it possible to trace Node.js applications the same way it's possible to trace applications that use threads by assigning a request id and using it in log output? There are third-party tools that can do it (NewRelic, Rollbar), but how do they work? How does one implement a similar functionality? I can do something like this

```
function foo(x, logger) {
  logger.info("Running foo")
}

function bar(a, b, logger) {
  logger.info(`Running bar with ${a} and ${b}`)
}

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  const requestId = uuid()
  const logger = {
    info: (msg) => console.log(`${requestId} ${msg}`)
  }

  foo(1, logger)
  bar(2, 3, logger)
}
```

But that requires explicitly passing logger object. What I want to do is to something like this in downstream functions

```
function foo(x) {
  const logger = require('logger')
  logger.info('Running foo') // => "[ce089d84-3679-42ae-b05c-2d0a071062f0] Running foo"
}
```

Comment: It is not clear what you're asking for help with.  It would be trivial to add a unique ID to each incoming http request object from a middleware handler and then that could be used in logging later on in the process.  Are you just asking how to do that?  Or you are asking for something more.  Rather than require your readers to go try to examine what features in NewRelic and Rollbar you might be requesting, please specify exactly what features you are looking for IN your question.

Comment: @jfriend00 what I'm asking is it possible to do it without explicitly passing a logger to all the functions that may need logging?

Comment: You'd have to first edit your question to show a code example of what you want the code to look like and what you want the log output to look like.  Still don't understand what you're trying to do.  If you want to limit your question to only people that have a familiarity with NewRelic or Rollbar, then you are a lot less likely to find anyone to help you.  On the other hand, if you edit your question to just show exactly what you're trying to achieve, then lots of people could potentially help you.  There is no global state in node.js that tells you what request you're current processing.

Comment: You can using `domain`, although it is pending deprecation. I will post an answer.

Comment: You can add a log method to each `request` object and then do `req.log()` and then that method can add the request id to every log.  But, you will have to have access to the `req` object to do that from anywhere you are logging.  There is no "request global state" that allows you to do this without access to the request object or some other object that you pass along.

Comment: @FrançoisP. seems that `continuation-local-storage` allow to have some kind of per-request global state.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with domain and express for example. You can test this script, just save it in a file run `npm i express uniqid` then `node index.js` and open browser at localhost:8080/test, just reload it and you will see the id changing.

```
const app = require('express')();
const uniqid = require('uniqid');

app.use((req, res, next) => {
    const nDomain = require('domain').create();
    nDomain.id = uniqid();
    nDomain.add(req);
    nDomain.add(res);
    nDomain.run(next);
    nDomain.on('error', next);
});

app.get('/test', function(req, res) {
    console.log(process.domain.id, 'id');
});

const server = app.listen(8080);
```

This way, just create a logger in a package which uses process.domain.id when logging. We use something similar at work to track which request triggered a log.

Beware, domain is pending deprecation. Please read the doc https://nodejs.org/api/domain.html